# How can I remove a screw broken off in a fan-rated junction box?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

[image: New house and contractor employee left it like this.]

It’s a new house and this how the contractor employees left it

Comment: Are you certain that it is a broken-off screw, and not an intact screw which some bright spark screwed in from the top of the box (like the other one to the left)?

Comment: A newly built house, I would be talking to the builder.  It should be his problem if his contractors left it like that.

Comment: My first attempt would be unscrewing it with a pair of Vice Grips.

Comment: which one, the left or the right screw

Comment: Are you sure those aren't the fan mounting crews??  Looks weird but don't wreck them until you're sure.

Comment: it sure looks like that was installed from the other side. (and is not actually broken)

Comment: Those look like studs in stand-offs (sleeve nuts or whatever). Doesn't look broken to me.

Answer (score 2):

I would use pliers or mole grips, while hoping that the part it is in does not snap.

Also have a pair of pointed pliers on hand just in case it rotates.